# VSCode - Dev container on docker not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-containers

I've been using the "Remote - Containers" extension to run python inside a docker container.
This has been working great for me for the last couple of month without any issues.

Today I've tried doing the same on a repo I haven't ran before. Went through the entire process and I'm connected to the docker container as usual.
I can run things in the terminal, and I can verify that everything I need installed is indeed installed.

The issue is - when I try to debug my code (by pressing F5, or even without debugging using ctrl+F5) nothing happens.
I can see the small play pause stop bar popping up - [image]
but it immediately closes and nothing runs...

When I look at the output of the python extension, I can see the line `DAP Server launched with command: /usr/bin/python3 /root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter` but again, nothing runs after that...

My launch.json looks like this -

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
    ]
}
```

and I'm running a simple python file -

```
a = 1
print(1)
```

with a breakpoint on each line which never triggers

This is really weird, as mentioned, I've been working this way for a long time and everything worked great up untill now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the python version I've had installed inside the docker and the version of the python extension.
I had `python 3.6.9` on `python extension v2022.10.1` which is incompatible.

The solution was to downgrade the python extension to version v2022.8.1 by adding the following to `devcontainer.json`  -

```
    "settings": {
        "extensions.autoUpdate": false,
        "extensions.autoCheckUpdates": false
    },
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python@2022.8.1",
    ]
```

Comment: how did you find the compatibility between python and the extension?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the following changes in `launch.json`:

> "justMyCode": true

change ****true**** to **false**.

2. Use the debugging options in the red box:

[image]

3. If the above does not take effect, please add the following content to `launch.json`:

   "debugStdLib":true,

Comment: vscode did not accept the  key `"debugStdLib"`  under `configurations`